# Android launch icon shows, but activity icons don't show in activity actionbars

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-manifest

[image]

I'm working with the "**MyFirstApp**" that "android create project" generates.  After building and installing the apk, I see the launcher icon, but -- this is what has me puzzled -- no icon shows on `MainActivity's` actionbar.  I would, of course, like the icon to appear at the top, on the actionbar that displays the MainActivity's name.

Here's my `AndroidManifest.xml`.  It's exactly what I got from "android create project" except
I've added that "android:icon" thing under "activity" (thinking this would solve my problem, which it did not).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.myfirstapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                  android:label="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have verified that I have appropriately-sized `ic_launcher.png` files in all the drawable-*dpi directories.

Comment: *no icon shows when I enter MainActivity* means? which icon? Icon in actionbar?

Comment: Yes, in the actionbar.  Sorry.

Comment: Show screenshot of how your activity looks like.

Comment: Please post your style.xml

Comment: in the `<activity />` tag, you should have a dot like this `.MainActivity`, also it didn't include a `android:style="@style/someStyle` attribute for you is really weird`, try opening up our `res` directory, then `values` folder, open the `styles.xml` file, locate the name of that style with the attribute `<style name="someName">`, then go back to your `Manifest.xml` file, add the `android:style="@style/the_name_of_the_style_here` to the `<application>` tag

Comment: Amiya: there is no style.xml.  Biu: I don't follow that.